# Can you change the node version on tonicdev.com?

Tags: node.js, tonic

Tonic allows you to run node code in the browser ... https://tonicdev.com/

But its currently running 0.12.7 of node

Can you change the node version when using Tonic? i've searched but can't find anything - thought someone might now.

My npm module fails on anything below node 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can in fact change the version, If you look under the title of the notebook you will see where it says "node 0.12" and if you click that you can select the version. Although the only currently supported versions are 0.10,0.12, and iojs 2.3. I would try seeing if iojs works for you, but if not, node 4 is coming shortly.